# Why aren’t these children headers centering?

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to center the `<div>` horizontally and vertically, and the children `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements should be centered horizontally relative to the parent `<div>`, so I applied a class for that, shown below. It isn’t centered, but aligned left instead. What’s going on?

```css
.centered {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hcentered {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.results {
  position: absolute;
}

.resultsText {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered results">
  <h1 class="hcentered resultsText">Header 1</h1>
  <h2 class="hcentered resultsText">Header 2</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h1` and `h2` are block level elements so by default they are 100% wide. Instead of all of the complex calculation, simply use `text-align: center;`